# IF-ELSE in Postgres

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, if-statement, select

I'm failing to translate a SQL query which was designed for MySQL into Postgres syntax. This is the query:

```
select if(sendonly = true, 'REJECT', 'OK') AS access from accounts where username = '%u' and domain = '%d' and enabled = true LIMIT 1;
```

This nice little function "if()" is not available in Postgres. My first attempts with some CASE clauses failed. What needs to be modified to make this query run in Postgres?

Comment: Did you do any research? Googling "postgres if else" reveals https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html which indicates there's a `IF-THEN-ELSE` structure.

Comment: @ceejayoz You might want to look at the page a little closer, that's about the server-side PL/pgSQL language, not SQL queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, you could use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sendonly = true THEN 'REJECT' ELSE 'OK' END AS access
FROM   accounts
WHERE  username = '%u' AND domain = '%d' AND enabled = true
LIMIT  1;
```

Or, as Postgres can evaluate booleans directly, you could trim this query down a bit:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sendonly THEN 'REJECT' ELSE 'OK' END AS access
FROM   accounts
WHERE  username = '%u' AND domain = '%d' AND enabled
LIMIT  1;
```